# Why does SoundCloud API cause the loop to list data in different orders

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, soundcloud

I made a JSON file to store SoundCloud URLs. Then my `$.each()` I load the data of the JSON file and based on the data I gather some more data from SoundCloud API. Somehow since SoundCloud causes my loop to load data in random orders, not the way the are in the JSON file.

Here is my code to get data and SoundCloud bit:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bLjOHIYsAy?indent=2", function(data){ //Link of the playlist

$.each(data.PlayListArray, function(key, val){ //navigate to array called PlayListArray
     var songLink = val.URL; // the value of URL in the array
        SC.get('/resolve', { url: songLink }, function(track) { //convert SoundCloud URLs to ids to get their data.
        $("#demo").append("<p id= "+ track.id + ">" + track.title + "</p>");
        });

});
});
```

The order is correct when I load data without having any SoundCloud code in the loop. But with soundcloud each time I refresh the pages, the order is different. Have a look at the demo please: http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Rw/

On JSFiddle please run the code copple of times and you see the order changes each time. Why is that? Any idea? Or any different way to loop through JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looping through each `SC.get` but it doesn't wait for `SC.get` to finish. Hence the order is different each time it's reloaded.

I would change it to use the callback parameter of `SC.get` for loading the next URL.

---

On further thought, I would suggest using jquery deferred function to chain the events.

Please see this post:
[Soundcloud Javascript API SC.get() will not allow me to change a variable outside of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615831/soundcloud-javascript-api-sc-get-will-not-allow-me-to-change-a-variable-outsid)

Comment: Thanks for your post. Do you mean I must make a function of SC.get and call it in each look? If not can you show it by code please. Thanks

Comment: I tired to use Callback as you suggested, not sure if I used it correctly, but however it does not show data this is the demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Rw/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Rw/4/). About the deferred method I could not figure out how it works. seems so complicated.